# Как переписать такой кусок код с Jquery на читый JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Главное из кода, я хочу понять функционал исчезновения всех элементов, кроме одно, который в событии мыши. Как это можно переписать на JS?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Alexxxsander/pen/dyqyjmV)

```
$(".point").on("mouseenter", function () {
  $(this).closest(".point-wrap").addClass("open");
  $(this).closest(".point-wrap").siblings('.point-wrap').css('opacity', '0');
});

$(".point").on("mouseleave", function () {
  $(this).closest(".point-wrap").removeClass("open");
  $(this).closest(".point-wrap").siblings('.point-wrap').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коментарии в коде должны помочь примерно понять, что скрывается в методах jQuery:

```js
// $(".point")
[...document.querySelectorAll('.point')]
  //.on("mouseenter", function () {
  .forEach((point) => { point.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    // $(this).closest(".point-wrap").addClass("open");
    this.closest('.point-wrap').classList.add('open');
    // $(this).closest(".point-wrap").siblings('.point-wrap')
    [...this.closest('.point-wrap').parentElement.children].filter((el) => 
      (el.classList.contains('point-wrap') && el != this.closest('.point-wrap'))
    )
    // .css('opacity', '0');
    .forEach((wrap) => { wrap.style.opacity = '0'; });
  });
});
/* Чуть оптимизированный код ниже аналогичен предыдущему, 
   за исключением значения прозрачности и удаления класса */
[...document.querySelectorAll('.point')].forEach((point) => {
  point.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    let parentWrap = this.closest('.point-wrap');
    parentWrap.classList.remove('open');
    [...parentWrap.parentElement.children].forEach((wrap) => {
      if (wrap.classList.contains('point-wrap') && wrap != parentWrap) wrap.style.opacity = '1';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}body{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center}.wrapper{position:relative;border:1px solid}img{height:400px;max-width:100%}ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}ul li{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;transition:.2s linear}ul li.open .point{background-color:#00bfff}ul li:first-child{top:10%;left:60%}ul li:nth-child(2){top:30%;left:40%}ul li:nth-child(3){top:15%;left:20%}ul li:nth-child(4){top:50%;left:80%}ul li:last-child{top:25%;left:70%}.point{cursor:pointer;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:100%;background-color:#dc143c;transition:.4s ease-in}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cakeshop.com.ua/images/6eRbfrsEzMM/h:1000/bG9jYWw/6Ly8vY2FrZXNob3AuY29tLnVhL3B1YmxpY19odG1sL3N0b3JhZ2UvYXBwL3B1YmxpYy9pbWcvcHJvZHVjdC85NDc0XzEuanBn" alt="Cat">
  <ul>
    <li class="point-wrap"><div class="point"></div></li>
    <li class="point-wrap"><div class="point"></div></li>
    <li class="point-wrap"><div class="point"></div></li>
    <li class="point-wrap"><div class="point"></div></li>
    <li class="point-wrap"><div class="point"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем делать так `[...document.querySelectorAll('.point')].forEach(...)`? Вы забыли что `querySelectorAll` возвращает `NodeList`? (У этого объекта уже есть метод `forEach`)

Comment: А ещё код который ниже второй пробежки по элементам, можно перенести прямо в первый цикл.

Comment: @ΝNL993, это я на автомате уже - часто требуются и другие методы массивов, поэтому сразу привожу ;-) По второму замечанию не совсем понял...

Comment: Я так и понял что вы про второе не поймёте :), я не совсем понятно объяснил. Короче, вы ведь в первом `forEach`, проходитесь по всем `.point`? У вас получается есть доступ к нему верно? Так вот, раз уж вы уже проходитесь по всем `.point` и вешаете слушатель `mouseenter`, почему бы сразу в том же `forEach` не повесить событие `mouseleave`, чтобы не проходится по элементам лишний раз? Думаю так будет понятней :)

Comment: @ΝNL993, теперь понятно. Мне понятно ;-) Но, ТС нужно было наглядно разобрать каждый метод, потому я не стал как-либо усложнять и модифицировать оригинальный код. А так, несомненно я переписал бы совсем по-другому.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let o=document.querySelectorAll("[class='point']");
let cnt=o.length;
for(i=0; i<cnt; i++){
o[i].addEventListener('mouseover',function(event){
  this.parentElement.className='point-wrap open';
  for(j=0;j<cnt;j++){
    if(o[j]!==this){
      o[j].parentElement.style.opacity='0';
    }
  }
});
};
for(i=0; i<cnt; i++){
o[i].addEventListener('mouseleave',function(event){
  this.parentElement.className='point-wrap';
    for(j=0;j<cnt;j++){
    if(o[j]!==this){
      o[j].parentElement.style.opacity='1';
    }
  }
});
};
```